# Force update ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a self-referencing loop that references the most recent associated record to see if it's caught up. However, it keeps referencing the first associated record, so it keeps going in an infinite loop. I think this is because the ActiveRecord transaction keeps running throughout the loop, so it never stops and updates itself.

Is there any way to force a model to reset itself before continuing on?

Here's my model (not that the exception raising is just so I can verify whether we've actually advanced to the next record).

```
class RecurringRule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_one :last_run, :class_name => "Transaction", :order => 'id DESC'
  has_many :transactions

  attr_accessible :period, :last_run_id

  after_create :destroy_if_period_empty

  def destroy_if_period_empty
    if !period?
      self.destroy
    end
  end

  def recur
    @count = @count || 0
    if @count > 0 then raise last_run.id.to_s end
    if last_run.created_at.to_date.advance(period.pluralize.to_sym => 1) >= Date.today 
      new = Transaction.new({
        amount: last_run.amount,
        person_id: last_run.person_id,
        organization_id: last_run.organization_id,
        recurring_rule_id: last_run.recurring_rule_id
      })
      new.save!
      @count += 1
      self.recur
    end
    return @count
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
Model.association(force_reload=true)
```

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association) for reference (it is valid also for has many relations)